# Combine @media with javascript to set display none/block

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I have a div panel somewhere on my page that should be hidden when the window size gets too small.

Works fine using this css:

```
#panel {display: block; }

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
   #panel { display: none; }
}
```

There is another rule that displays a button which should make the #panel visible onclick.

```
#panel {display: block; }
#button {display: none; }
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
   #panel { display: none; }
   #button {display: block; }
}
```

The javascript looks like this:

```
 $("#button").click(function() { $("#panel").toggle(); });
```

there are some other rules as well that make the panel appear friendlier... no need to explain this. The problem is: when you once clicked the button and changed the display state of the panel to on and off again. That means the `display:none` property was set by the javascript, the panel will not be displayed again when you resize the window > 1000px. The default style of the panel will not be applied, even if you create some rule like `@media(min-width: 1000px)`.. the js seems to have priority.. so what is the best way to combine media queries and js?

Comment: you may be worrying about something that will likely never happen.  People don't go around resizing their browsers unless they are demo'ing a responsive site.

Comment: hehe.. nice one.. probably your are right.. but if someone does it the page will break completly. and this should better not happen..

Answer (score 1):

You could add an event listener for the window resize event that forces the panel to be visible when the window is resized to a width > 1000px.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1000) {
        $("#panel").show();
    }
});
```

As soon as `toggle`, `show`, or `hide` are called that will trump whatever is in the CSS.

Comment: yes.. thanks. that's what i am doing at the moment, because i dont have a better solution.. but in that case you dont need the @media query at all, because you can also hide the #panel in the else-part : ) i was just wondering how you can be sure about the state of the objects.. something may break totally if you use both types..

Comment: ```toggle```, ```show```, and ```hide``` modify the element's style tag, so it will always override what is in the CSS. I think it makes sense to use a combination of CSS and javascript in this case.